# How to access data using reverse foreign key reference in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model named UserProfile and a model PersonalInformation. I would like to fetch all the data of PersonalInformation using UserProfile model when the user is logged into the webiste but i have a foreign key refernce in the PersonalInformation model with the UserProfile model so how do i fetch the personal information using UserProfile model?

User Profile Model :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
"""Represents a user's model inside our system"""

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%y/%m/%d/')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    highest_degree_earned = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    graduation_year = models.IntegerField(default=2020, blank=False)
```

Personal Information Model :

```
class PersonalInformation(models.Model):
    """Represents a user's personal Infromation inside our system"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10 ,blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    college_university = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

Comment: You sahred twice a model named `PersonalInformation`? Is there a specific reason why you used two models, and not just added all fields to the *same* model?

Comment: that was a slight mistake!

Comment: you would be better off making this a OneToOneField and then follow docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the code, you are showing you have the names of the models wrong. The UserProfile model name is set as PersonalInformation, change it or the migrations won't work (it's not accepted on the database no matter which one you're using). 
Referent to the question you're asking, to fetch the related instance of PersonalInformation of a certain UserProfile instance you should just query the next:

```
user = UserProfile.objects.get(id='') #Introduce the id of the user you want to fetch its personal information.
user.personalinformation_set.all() # This will return you a QuerySet with all the related instances of PersonalInformation class.
user.personalinformation_set.get(id='') #To get a specific one or you may use a filter to get a filtered QS.
```

If you want, you can use the `related_name` attribute for ForeignKey class in order to set a different name from `personalinformation_set`.
I recommend you too to read the Django documentation, it's really well explained and clear I think:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

As I've seen in a comment, you may also think to use a OneToOne relation instead of ForeignKey if you only expect one instance of PersonalInformation per User. The documentation is at: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/